# Поле texarea и button

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Не силён в коде, поэтому обращаюсь за помощью, как можно соединить кнопку с текстовым полем, чтобы при клике по кнопке в поле автоматом вставлялся текст. Суть в следующем, на работе нужно много печатать слова приветствия и работать с комбинацией Ctrl+c+v, есть ли возможность создать кнопку которая будет писать в текстовое поле "Здравствуйте" через код элемента или через консоль как скрипт, так как к внутреннему коду нет доступа чтобы менять изнутри.

Comment: ваша цель автоматически вводить какие-то вещи на форме (страничке)?

Comment: Цель создать button, вывести его например в правый край страницы и задать фиксированное значение, далее соединить его с текстовым полем texarea. В button задать слово по умолчанию. Т.е при клике по кнопке, чтобы этот текст вставлялся в texarea

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ:

```html
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
<button onclick='document.querySelector("textarea[name=text]").value+="Здрасьте, я ваша тётя"'>Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: К сожалению, возвращаюсь с своим вопросом, данный код удалось применить только на обычные текстовые поля с присвоением name, однако там где нужно нет name, там textarea просто заключён в <div> и ничего более, мне удалось немного изменить ваш код вписав другие данные, кнопка заработала, однако после автоматической вставки, если я тыкаю в текстовое окно чтобы что-то дописать, весь текст стирается автоматом, а кнопка отправить неактивна